# how to echo values from this array country impression record

Tags: php

```
Array ( 
   [Pakistan] => Array ( 
        [impression] => 110 
        [request] => 8 
        [click] => 5 
    ) 
    [India] => Array ( 
        [impression] => 20 
        [request] => 50 
        [click] => 5 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: did you tried something? please post your effort (edit your question and add your code what you tried so far). For hint use [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Use looping statement - `foreach`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this -

```
$result = Array ( 
    [Pakistan] => Array ( 
        [impression] => 110 
        [request] => 8 
        [click] => 5 
    ) 
    [India] => Array ( 
        [impression] => 20 
        [request] => 50 
        [click] => 5 
    ) 
);

foreach($result as $key=>$value)
{
    print_r($value['impression']); //try this to print impression
}
```

Hope this will help you.